# EDMX -> Code First generator

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

Is there an existing way to generate EF code first from an existing EDMX>

I know that there's reverse poco generators that go from a connection string, but wee have a legacy solution which has a massive schema with an inordinate number of customisations made (renames, extra relationships no in the underlying schema, etc) which business code heavily relies on.  We'd like to generate the code first classes without breaking any part of the system then code with Code First Migrations.

Answer (score 1):

There's no automated way to translate EDMX mapping to Code-First Mapping (Fluent or Attribute-based).  The best you can do is copy the generated entity classes from under the .EDMX and recreate the mappings in the EDMX using the Fluent API.

Note there are things like DefiningQuery that simply don't exist in Code-First.